# Clojure(Script) webapp on Heroku - deployment options for gzipping static resources?

Tags: heroku, clojure, clojurescript

I have a Clojure(Script) webapp deployed via Heroku - what are my options for compressing (via gzip) the static resources?

Here's what I've gathered so far:

- [`ring-gzip-middleware`](https://github.com/mikejs/ring-gzip-middleware) would gzip everything, but I don't want to repeatedly do this for static resources.
- [this article](http://cemerick.com/2011/04/22/adding-gzip-compression-to-a-clojure-webapp-in-30-seconds/) suggests deploying as a regular java webapp and specifying the gzip init param for the Jetty DefaultServlet in web.xml. I'd rather keep my deployment simple w/ the [Heroku Clojure buildpack](https://github.com/heroku/heroku-buildpack-clojure) if possible.
- [this thread](https://github.com/http-kit/http-kit/issues/19#issuecomment-14274960) suggests using a nginx reverse proxy. This sounds good promising, in conjunction with the [nginx-buildpack](https://github.com/ryandotsmith/nginx-buildpack) - does anyone have more details about how to achieve this?